# Combining custom constraint validator annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation

So I have created a custom constraint validator annotation like so:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = PostcodeValidator.class)
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Postcode {
  String message() default "not a well-formed postcode";
  Class<?>[] groups() default {};
  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

and I wanted to use it in combination with others like so:

```
@NotEmpty
@Postcode
private final String postcode;
```

But when attempting to test this I get the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key not a well-formed postcode
```

I was expecting it to fail the `@NotEmpty` constraint.

I know I can use composition to include one constraint within the other, but my question is, is it possible to use them as I am? And if so, what am I doing wrong?

Cheers,

Comment: I had the same Problem. With a solution. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75724586/how-to-register-a-custom-constraint-validator-for-standard-bean-validation-annot